# What function is used to estimate regression coefficients of a CoxPH model via coxph() in R

Tags: r, cox-model, beta-distribution, scoring-rules

I am trying to understand the step by step process of how to estimate the beta coefficients in a CoxPH model. I first get the beta estimates using the coxph() function in r for a sample dataset of six records. Then I manually calculated the partial likelihood function, L(β) and partial log-likelihood function , l(β). If I use these functions in R to estimate beta coefficients using optim(), it gives the corrects estimated value; fun1() for L(β) and fun2() for l(β)

Here is my code:

```
##########coxph() in r to get beta estimate#############
test_cox_sbp <- coxph(Surv(Time, Status) ~ SBP , data = testd_sbp)
summary(test_cox_sbp)

########## L(β)#############
fun1 = function(beta1){
  h1 = exp(120*beta1)
  h2 = exp(130*beta1)
  h3 = exp(140*beta1)
  h4 = exp(150*beta1)
  h5 = exp(160*beta1)
  h6 = exp(145*beta1)
  p1=h1/(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6)
  p2=h3/(h3+h4+h5+h6)
  p3=h4/(h4+h5+h6)
  return(p1*p2*p3)
}

result <- optim(par=0, fn = fun1, method = "L-BFGS-B",
                control=list(fnscale = -1),
                lower = -3, upper = 1)
########## l(β)#############
fun2 = function(beta1){
  h1 = exp(120*beta1)
  h2 = exp(130*beta1)
  h3 = exp(140*beta1)
  h4 = exp(150*beta1)
  h5 = exp(160*beta1)
  h6 = exp(145*beta1)
  p1 = ln(h1)-ln(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6)
  p2 = ln(h3)-ln(h3+h4+h5+h6)
  p3 = ln(h4)-ln(h4+h5+h6)
  return(p1+p2+p3)
}

result <- optim(par=0, fn = fun2, method = "L-BFGS-B",
                control=list(fnscale = -1),
                lower = -3, upper = 1)
result$par
```

All the functions above including the built-in function in R return beta1 = -0.2206. But when I use the score function U(β) which is the first derivative of l(β); fun3 in the code below , it doesn't return the correct value

```
########## U(β)#############
fun3 = function(beta1){
  h1 = exp(120*beta1)
  h2 = exp(130*beta1)
  h3 = exp(140*beta1)
  h4 = exp(150*beta1)
  h5 = exp(160*beta1)
  h6 = exp(145*beta1)
  a1 = 120 * h1
  a2 = 130 * h2
  a3 = 140 * h3
  a4 = 150 * h4
  a5 = 160 * h5
  a6 = 145 * h6
  
  p1 = 120-((a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6)/(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6))
  p2 = 140-((a3+a4+a5+a6)/(h3+h4+h5+h6))
  p3 = 150-((a4+a5+a6)/(h4+h5+h6))
  return(p1+p2+p3)
}

result <- optim(par=0, fn = fun3, method = "L-BFGS-B",
                control=list(fnscale = -1),
                lower = -3, upper = 1)
result$par
```

If this is not the correct way to estimate the beta coefficient but then how does the coxph() function in R return beta coefficient estimates. What is the main function behind the coxph() function in R

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/0a4e136a76434fb423f7dc1b1550f396) is a gist that attempts to reproduce the optimization examples for `fun1`, `fun2`, and `fun3` in Python. For `fun1` and `fun2` I also obtained `-0.22061141`, but for `fun3` I obtained `-3` which happens to be one of the bounds of parameter constraints.

Comment: Looks like [`CoxPHFitter` in `lifelines`](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html) estimates the Cox proportional hazards model in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code relating to `fun3` is trying to “optimize” the score function. You need instead to solve for the value of $\beta$ at which the score function equals 0.

```
root <- uniroot(fun3,c(-3,1))
root$root
# [1] -0.2206112
```

That's the value of $\beta$ you found by minimizing the (log) partial likelihood.